# Unable to install speech_recognition(pyaudio)

Tags: python, windows, pip, speech-recognition, pyaudio

***STEP BY STEP PROCCES of how i got the error***

The command I ran:

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

Log:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting SpeechRecognition
  Using cached SpeechRecognition-3.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (32.8 MB)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: SpeechRecognition
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Successfully installed SpeechRecognition-3.8.1
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

The code I wrote:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr 
Assistant = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = Assistant.getProperty('voices')
Assistant.setProperty('voices',voices[0].id)

print('voice set to ' + voices[0].id)

def Speak(audio):
    print("      ")
    Assistant.say(audio)
    print("      ")
    Assistant.runAndWait()

def takecommand():
    command = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("listening...........")
        command.pause_threshold(1)
        audio = command.listen(source)

        try:
            print("Recognizing")
            query = command.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
            print(f"You said : {query}")
        except Exception as error:
            print('please say that again , sir?')
            return None
        
        return query

Speak("Hello ,sir")
takecommand()
```

The error I got:

```
      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "d:\coding\Artificial intelligence COURSE\JARVIS\app.py", line 33, in <module>
    takecommand()
  File "d:\coding\Artificial intelligence COURSE\JARVIS\app.py", line 17, in takecommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I tried:

```
pip install PyAudio
```

and I got:

```
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Skipping PyAudio as it is not installed.
PS D:\coding\Artificial intelligence COURSE\JARVIS> pip install PyAudio
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyAudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcd0evem\\pyaudio_a0f1c2c379a74eaf8d4dab779f566e4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcd0evem\\pyaudio_a0f1c2c379a74eaf8d4dab779f566e4e\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6pe_k76o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kcd0evem\pyaudio_a0f1c2c379a74eaf8d4dab779f566e4e\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG 
/MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -IC:\Python310\include -IC:\Python310\Include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files 
obuild\temp.win-amd64-3.10\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    C:\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcd0evem\\pyaudio_a0f1c2c379a74eaf8d4dab779f566e4e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Toshiba\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kcd0evem\\pyaudio_a0f1c2c379a74eaf8d4dab779f566e4e\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6pe_k76o\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Python310\Include\PyAudio' Check the logs for full command output.     
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -p (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution - (c:\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/#requirements

Answer (score 0):

Go to the error path. In my case it is c:\python39\lib\site-packages. And delete the folder.[image]

Comment: Didnt work :-((

Comment: I'm sorry for this bruh